# Mixed Content The page at was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure resource This request has been blocked the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, resources, mixed

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's no way to disable mixed content using javascript but you can add this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

to your HTML to allow mixed content

Comment: This does not appear to have any effect on the current version of Chrome. See my answer below on the Chrome flag.

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome, you can treat a url as safe via this flag:

`chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`

You can enter multiple protocol and urls, even using local IP addresses in a comma delimited list. E.g.
`http://192.168.1.142, ws://192.168.1.142`

Problems: 1. Requires trust or knowledge on part of the user (browser starts with a warning message about degraded functionality), 2. Chrome specific. 3. Slightly reduces security.

Answer (score 3):

to allow **Mixed Content**:
1- add this **meta tag** to the page (HTML File)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

2- add **unsafe_url** for **referrerPolicy** to your **fetch** requests if you get **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**
example:

```
fetch('http://URL', {
    // ...
    referrerPolicy: "unsafe_url" 
});
```

> Warning: This policy will leak potentially-private information from
> HTTPS resource URLs to insecure origins. Carefully consider the impact
> of this setting.

for more info check these 2 documentations:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy
2. https://javascript.info/fetch-api

Comment: referrerPolicy: "unsafe_url" does not appear to have any effect in Chrome.

Comment: Neither of these appear to have any effect in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Add below to .htaccess

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
```

This will let the browser try to load HTTP content on the HTTPS page in HTTPS.

Comment: This answer solved my issue but , can you explain how this happened. Page worked fine for like 1 month and then suddenly this morning this happened

Comment: @AnelHodžić Probably because the browser updated and the new version started enforcing mixed content errors.

Comment: This does not appear to have any effect in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with HTTPS page requesting detecting Ajax folder existence `https://domanin.name/folder` get mix-content with 301 redirect error with header location changed to `http:` works fine with `https://domanin.name/folder/` if you don't use `/` end of the file server redirect destination with adding `/` but why `http:` instead `https:` strange behavior!