# This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS react / spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, iis, https

I checked all similar error but none of them solved my problem. I have a React and Spring Boot app. Frontend and Backend are separated. They both work in windows server 2012. I take build of react app and add it to IIS Manager. I created a certificate from ZeroSSL and I added the certificate to IIS manager. When I go to my web page it says secured it works fine. But When I make any request to my java spring boot backend. It gives error. Because it makes request in https. but I wrote in "http" not "https".

It gives below error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://webpage.com/#/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://IP:8080/api/login/. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

After that I tried to convert my java backend app http to https,
I added these to application.properties

```
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store=certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

I created same certificate and add under application.properties file but still gives me error. I am really stuck on it. any there is nobody to near to help me. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Where did you put your .p12 file?  In all likelihood, should be in src/main/resources/keystore
Here are some resources that might help:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-examples/
https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

Comment: yes there src/main/resources/keystore

Comment: You didn't mention clearly above how you host the Java web app. Thus, you have to edit the question and reveal more.

Comment: I enabled my spring boot https but now I am getting ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, when I make request to backend https:/localhost:5433. certificate is valid I dont know why I am getting this error

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765238/mixed-content-the-page-at-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure-resour
In the JSP page, just add this meta: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` to your HTML to allow mixed content.